# Cи. Сортировка методом слияния

Tags: c, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием, слияние

Нужно сделать код сортировки чисел в порядке возрастания на Си методом слияния. Не понимаю почему не работает данный код. Сортирует элементы лишь частично, финальный массив не выводиться в порядке возрастания.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define N 1000

    void merge (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2) return;
    int mid = n / 2;
    merge(a, mid);
    merge(a + mid, n - mid);
    int h = 1;
 
    int *c = (int*)malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    int step;
    while (h < n){

    step = h;
    int i = 0;
    int j = mid;
    int k = 0;
      for (i = 0, j = mid; i < mid && j < n; k++)
      if (a[i] < a[j]) c[k] = a[i++];
      else c[k] = a[j++];

        h = h * 2;
      while (i < step)
            {
              c[k] = a[i];
              i++; k++;
            }
        while ((j < (mid + step)) && (j<n))
        {
          c[k] = a[j];
          j++; k++;
        }
        step = step + h;
          }
          h = h * 2;
          
         for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                    a[i] = c[i];
}

    int main(){
  int a[N];
  
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    a[i] = rand() % 100;
  
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  merge(a, N);
  
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поясните, что значит "не работает". "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе."

Comment: Он сработает если обе половины массива (до и после mid)  будут упорядочены. Т.е. тут не хватает рекурсивных  вызовов merge для каждой из половинок перед кодом, собственно, слияния. Внимание, массив из одного элемента очевидно упорядочен.

Comment: Похоже, никто не собирается учить новичков моей любимой сортировке... Начните вот так -- `void merge (int *a, int n) { if (n < 2) return; int mid = n / 2; merge(a, mid); merge(a + mid, n - mid); // а тут код слияния уже отсортированных половинок }` / Кстати, сам код слияния можно написать гораздо проще, чем у вас `for (i = 0, j = mid; i < mid && j < n; k++)   if (a[i] < a[j]) c[k] = a[i++];  else c[k] = a[j++];`  / Осталось скопировать хвосты половинок (реально копироваться будет только один) в `c[]` и скопировать его обратно в a[]

Comment: @avp элементы сортируются, но иногда  встречаться вставки меньших элементов(например:2 2 3 4 0 5 5)

Comment: @Masha, это в том коде, что в тексте вопроса? Вы актуальный код приведите.

Comment: @avp, готово, код изменен

Comment: У вас какие-то совершенно не нужные действия с `step` и `h`. В результате берете данные откуда-то вне массива. Вообще, весь внешний цикл `while (h < n){` не нужен. Оставьте слияние основной части массивов `for (i = 0, j = mid; i < mid && j < n; k++) if (...) ...`. Пересылка хвостов тоже просто пишется (никакой step там не нужен) -- `while (i < mid) c[k++] = a[i++]; while (j < n) c[k++] = a[j++];` С обратным копированием все выглядит нормально.

Comment: Кардинально улучшать использование временной памяти будем?

Comment: @avp, код работает, спасибо вам большое за помощь! Память пока не важна, главное было с алгоритмом разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм сортировки слиянием заключается в рекурсивном делении массива пополам до массивов размером в один элемент (такой массив очевидно упорядочен) с последующим слиянием 2-х упорядоченных массивов. Алгоритм обеспечивает [устойчивую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (stable) сортировку.
(конечно, в данном примере сортируются целые числа, которые неотличимы друг от друга, однако, в ряде задач, когда сортируются структуры по некоторому ключу, устойчивость может быть необходима)

Этот алгоритм имеет сложность O(N log N) и требует дополнительную память на фазе слияния для получения отсортированного результата.   Обычно в реализациях слияния  требуется память того же размера, что и исходный массив, но тут рассмотрен вариант, когда достаточно дополнительной памяти размером с половину исходного массива.

Мы можем сократить память в два раза, поскольку в процессе сортировки получаем сливаемые массивы одинакового (второй может быть на один элемент длиннее) размера, которые расположены рядом, а результат слияния замещает их данные. Поэтому можно скопировать первый массив во вспомогательную память и начать размещать отсорированный результат поверх элементов первого. К тому моменту, когда данные результата достигнут второго массива, его начальные элементы уже будут скопированы в область результата.

На практике имеет смысл остановиться в разбиении массива при достижении резмера в несколько десятков элементов и сортировать такие массивы какой-нибудь простой квадратичной сортировкой (например, вставками). Дело тут в том, что накладные расходы на каждый шаг  в рекурсивном разделении и последующем слиянии  превышают подобные накладные расходы в простой сортировке.

Вот пример кода, реализующего такую сортировку для массива целых чисел.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MSORT_LIM 20   // при таком размере массива выполняем сортировку подмассива вставками


// сортировка вставками, 
// используется для коротких подмассивов, получающихся при разбиении исходного
void
i_sort (int *a, int n)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    int t = a[i],
      j;
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && t < a[j]; j--)
      a[j + 1] = a[j];
    a[j + 1] = t;
  }
}

// основная функция сортировки слиянием
// рекурсивно делит пополам исходный массив на 2 подмассива
// производит отсортированный массив путем слияния уже отсортированных подмассивов
// `t[]` вспомогательный массив достаточного размера для хранения самого длинного подмасива 
void
i_merge_srt (int *a, int n, int *t)
{
  if (n < MSORT_LIM) {
    i_sort(a, n);
    return;
  }

  // делим масссив пополам и рекурсивно сортируем половинки
  int mid = n / 2;
  i_merge_srt(a, mid, t);
  i_merge_srt(a + mid, n - mid, t);

  // Далее код слияния 2-х отсортированных половин в один сортированный массив

  // копируем первый подмассив во вспомогательную память, 
  // использую системную (обычно весьма быструю) функцию копирования
  memcpy(t, a, mid  * sizeof(*a));

  // копируем элементы 2-х подмассивов в область результата (начинающуюся поверх первого подмассива)
  // в порядке их возрастания (получаем отсортированную последовательность)
  int k = 0, i, j;  
  for (i = 0, j = mid; i < mid && j < n; k++)
    if (t[i] <= a[j])   // условие `<=` обеспечивает устойчивость сортировки
      a[k] = t[i++];
    else
      a[k] = a[j++];

  // скопируем "хвост" первого подмассива в результат
  memcpy(a + k, t + i, (mid - i) * sizeof(*a));
}

// функция-обертка над i_merge_srt(), обеспечивающая вспомогательную память достаточного размера
// возвращает 1 при успехе, 0 при невозможности выделить память
int
merge_srt (int *a, int n)
{
  if (n < 2)
    return 1;  // такой массив уже упорядочен

  int *tmp = malloc((n / 2) * sizeof(*a));
  if (!tmp)
    return 0;
  
  i_merge_srt(a, n, tmp);
  free(tmp);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `#define MSORT_LIM 20` почему именно 20? Из эмпирических соображений или эксперименты какие проводили? (Ничего не имею против данного конкретного значения, просто любопытно.)

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, здесь не проводил. Вообще, это трудно измеряемая величина. Как-то на другой машине делал, от 10 до 70 практически одинаковое ускорение, в одном замере то, в другом другое.